# SQL join multiple fields w/ a NULL criteria

Tags: sql, join, null, adodb

I want to identify shipments from a table which have routes that have established contracts for the particular route, but the wrong carrier was used.

[image: Shipment Table]
[image: Contract Table]

[image: Combined Table]

I am able to separately query and identify the Contract Types where the Route/Carrier match and where the Route has not been contracted for any Carrier.  Respectively, this is how I did those:

```
SELECT s.*,c.*
FROM Shipments s
  INNER JOIN Contracts c ON s.Route=c.Route and s.Carrier=c.Carrier;
  
SELECT s.*,c.*
FROM Shipments s
  LEFT JOIN Contracts c ON s.Route=c.Route 
WHERE c.Route IS NULL;
```

The row that is yellow highlighted, however, I need help to solve. It is the case where a Route has been contracted for, but the wrong carrier was used, thus negated the effort of negotiating the contract (yes, this is a real world scenario).

I've tried the following, but they do not isolate the yellow line, which is my goal.

```
SELECT s.*,c.*
FROM Shipments s
  LEFT JOIN Contracts c ON s.Route=c.Route and s.Carrier!=c.Carrier;

SELECT s.*,c.*
FROM Shipments s
  LEFT JOIN Contracts c ON s.Route=c.Route and s.Carrier=c.Carrier
  WHERE c.Carrier IS NULL;

SELECT s.*,c.*
FROM Shipments s
  LEFT JOIN Contracts c ON s.Route=c.Route
  WHERE c.Carrier IS NULL;
```

I'm trying to implement this in Excel VBA using ADODB, but for the moment, I'm really interested in just understanding conceptually how I would achieve this generically in SQL -- if possible -- or what a better strategy to do this would be. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why the `Route = 3` and `Carrier = D` row is acceptable, but not the highlighted one?

Comment: @AaronDietz Not sure I follow your question, but Route 3 was never put out to bid, and thus no contract exists with any carrier; the route was not bid (no contract).  Route 2 **was** put out to bid, and Carrier C was awarded the contract for Route 2.  Despite having a contract established, a shipment on Route 2 was sent on Carrier D who does NOT have a contract (presumably costing my company more).  Is that more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an additional join to see if the route has a contract and then `CASE` logic:

```
SELECT s.*,
       (CASE WHEN cr.route IS NULL THEN 'Route has no contract'
             WHEN c.route IS NULL THEN 'Route assigned to wrong carrier'
             ELSE 'Correct'
        END)
FROM Shipments s LEFT JOIN
     Contracts c 
     ON s.Route = c.Route AND s.carrier = c.carrier LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT c.Route
      FROM Contracts c
     ) cr
     ON cr.Route = s.Route
```

Comment: This answer provides exactly what I needed.  I initially thought this was equivalent to @eshirvana's answer, but then applying both proposed answers to the real world data, I realized I got records multiplied with the other answer that I don't get with yours -- the "SELECT DISTINCT" and limiting to only the Route in the 2nd LEFT JOIN is very key.  This is the answer I needed.  Thank you.

Comment: @wackojacko1997 select distinct fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want to do:

```
select distinct s.* 
    , c1.*
    , case when c1.carrier = c2.carrier 
        then 'Correct carrier'
     when s.carrier <> c2.carrier  
        then 'wrong carrier'
     else 'No contract' 
     end as contractType
from Shipments s
left join Contracts  c1
    on s.route = c1.route
    and s.carrier = c1.carrier
left join Contracts  c2
    on s.route = c2.route
where (
    c1.route = c2.route 
    and c1.carrier = c2.carrier
    )
    or ( c1.route is null )
```

Comment: This answer does the entire unified table, and it works when tested in SQL Fiddle.  I think this is what I'm looking for...I'll be back later today to fully examine this. Thank you.

Comment: After careful examination, this answer breaks down under circumstances where the Contract table has multiple contracts for a Route with multiple carriers, but a shipment is performed with non-contracted carrier.  This answer results in duplicating the shipment in the final table in an undesirable way.  I will elaborate this in an addendum to the question at the top.  I do appreciate your answer, though, because it required thought and experimentation.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.*,c.*
FROM Shipments s
LEFT JOIN Contracts c ON s.Route=c.Route and s.Carrier=c.Carrier;
```

if `c.Route` is null, those shipments have no contract.